# проблема с обработкой столкновения

Tags: java, swing, разработка-игр

в классе `math` есть метод `p` отвечающий за движение персонажа

перед движением он проверяет то место куда пойдет

но почему-то это работает не во все направления

с 2х сторон черного квадрата он не может пройти а с 2х других может

```
package test3;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class maen {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        draw d=new draw();
        math m=new math();
        m.setplace();

        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(d);

        JButton b1=new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                m.p(1);
                d.rp();
            }
        });

        JButton test=new JButton();
        JButton b2=new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                m.p(2);
                d.rp();
            }
        });

        JButton b3=new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                m.p(3);
                d.rp();
            }
         });

        JButton b4=new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                m.p(4);
                d.rp();
            }
        });

        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.add(b3);
        f.add(b4);
    }

}

class draw extends JPanel{
    math m=new math();

    public void rp(){
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.fillRect((x*10)+20,(y*10)+20,10,10);

                if(m.xy[x][y]>0){

                    switch(m.xy[x][y]){
                    case 1:
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                        g.fillRect((x*10)+20,(y*10)+20,10,10);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillRect((x*10)+20,(y*10)+20,10,10);
                        break;
                    }

                }    
            }
        }
    }
}

class math{
    static int[][] xy=new int[10][10];

    int x=4;
    int y=8;

    public void setplace(){
        this.xy[6][6]=2;
        this.xy[3][3]=2;
    }

    public void p(int bv){
        int x=this.x;
        int y=this.y;
        int xb=x;
        int yb=y;
        int xp=x++;
        int yp=y++;
        int xm=x--;
        int ym=y--;

        switch(bv){
            case 1:
                if(xy[xp][y]<2)
                    this.x--;
                break;
            case 2:
                if(xy[xm][y]<2)
                    this.x++;   
                break;
            case 3:
                if(xy[x][yp]<2)
                    this.y--;
                break;
            case 4:
                if(xy[x][ym]<2)
                    this.y++;   
                break;  
        }

        System.out.println(this.x+" "+this.y);
        this.xy[xb][yb]=0;
        this.xy[this.x][this.y]=1;

        System.out.println("xym"+xy[xm][y]+xy[x][ym]+xy[x][y]);
        System.out.println("xyp"+xy[xp][y]+xy[x][yp]+xy[x][y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int xp=x++;` вы понимаете что делает эта строка?
`int y = 1; int a = y++; System.out.println(a + " " + y)` что выведет такой код?

Comment: @iksuy "int xp=x++" прибавляет 1 к "x" чтобы проверить следующую координату  а тот код выводит координаты

Comment: конкретно, какие значения выведет этот код: `int y = 1; int a = y++; System.out.println(a + " " + y)` ?

Comment: @NINZA iksuy имел ввиду примерно следующее: чем отличаются `y++`, `++y` и `y+1`. Тот код выведет `1 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void p( int bv ) {
    int start_x = x;
    int start_y = y;
    int x_plus = x+1;
    int y_plus = y+1;
    int x_minus = x-1;
    int y_minus = y-1;

    switch ( bv ) {
        case 1://LEFT
            if ( x_minus < 0 )
                return;
            if ( xy[x_minus][y] < 2 )
                this.x = x_minus;
            break;
        case 2://RIGHT
            if ( x_plus > 9 )
                return;
            if ( xy[x_plus][y] < 2 )
                this.x = x_plus;
            break;
        case 3://UP
            if ( y_minus < 0 )
                return;
            if ( xy[x][y_minus] < 2 )
                this.y = y_minus;
            break;
        case 4://DOWN
            if ( y_plus > 9 )
                return;
            if ( xy[x][y_plus] < 2 )
                this.y = y_plus;
            break;
    }
    this.xy[start_x][start_y] = 0;
    this.xy[this.x][this.y] = 1;
}
```

PS: Давайте переменным человекопонятные наименования; направления движения можно оформить в виде `enum`а; имена классов принято писать с заглавной.
PPS: Чем проще и примитивнее выглядит код - тем лучше: ваш стиль написания трудночитаем( именно этот метод ), т.к. чтобы понять какое значение вы хотите присвоить приходится пробегать глазами весь код выше, при этом учитывая что использовался постинкремент. Всё это осложняет поиск ошибки и хотя скорее всего она была проста, было легче переписать чем разобраться.